# Apple Store App Rejection - UIBackgroundModes

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, ios-background-mode

I'm new to React Native. I made a simple app that contains my youtube videos. When I uploaded this to the store they sent me the following message:

> Guideline 2.5.4 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> Your app declares support for external-accessory in the
> UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not declare any
> external accessory protocols supported by your app. The external
> accessory background mode is intended for apps that communicate with
> hardware accessories through the External Accessory framework.
>
> Next Steps
>
> If your app is meant to work with external hardware, supported
> protocols must be included in the
> UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key in your app's Info.plist
> file - and the hardware's PPID # should be provided in the Review
> Notes field of your app in App Store Connect.
>
> Additionally, your app must be authorized by MFi to use the desired
> hardware. If you are not yet in the MFi Program, you can enroll at MFi
> program.
>
> Please either revise your Info.plist to include the
> UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key and update your Review Notes
> to include the PPID # - or remove the external-accessory value from
> the UIBackgroundModes key.

I use 2 background modes, background fetch and remote notification in my app. I don't use external accessory communication but when I built the application, all three were selected. If I build my app again without "external accessory communication" will the problem be solved?

[image]

Comment: I believe If you build your app again without "external accessory communication", the problem will be solved